# How to mange language syntax/indent configuage by vundle?

Tags: vim

I just start using vundle, I'm curious that where should I place my 
language(may python, ruby, php) syntax/indentation configuration file.

When I put these configuration file in the normal place `.vim/syntax`,
`.vim/indent`, they worked, but they didn't work when I put them under `.vim/bundle`.

I wondering is it suppose to be in somewhere under `.vim/bundle` if I want vundle help me to manage these configuration scripts?

Thanks.

Regrads.

Comment: Would it work if you do something like `~/.vim/bundle/mybundle/syntax/python.vim`?

Comment: I tried that like you said, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to put your custom scripts is `.vim/after`.

The reason is you may always want your custom scripts take the last effect. For example, vim has default actions on python files, then the installed plugins will add more. You may not be satisfied with all them so you roll out your own, which will be the last to call in loading.

You can either version control the `/after` folder or whole `./vim` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Vundle only helps you managing your own configuration if you put it in a (Git(Hub)) repository and reference that in Vundle, just like other repositories. You still need to stick to the normal `'runtimepath'` hierarchy; i.e. for a Python filetype plugin, you'd put them into `ftplugin/python.vim` inside your repository, and that gets installed by Vundle into `~/.vim/bundle/my-python-filetype/ftplugin/python.vim`.

On the other hand, if you just maintain your own customizations on the system (without a repository), Vundle doesn't help you much, and you can just keep them in the normal location.

Comment: still not working. I just give up, leave these configuration in the directory `.vim/indent`, `.vim/syntax`.  Thanks

Comment: You can use the `:scriptnames` command to see what got sourced, and `:set rtp?` tells you the directory roots being searched. Maybe that helps with troubleshooting.